# Convert sys timestamp to UTC

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a requirement to convert my systimestamp to UTC time. I found below sql through google.
Will it work for every possible scenario? For example my oracle server is following EST time. 
Will this query give the correct UTC during EST daylight saving period as well?

```
Select sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the server is configured correctly and that all the appropriate time zone patches are applied, that should return the correct result.  If "every possible scenario" includes scenarios where the server is misconfigured or patches are missing, then nothing you do solely on the server would work.